# Controller not loading value from factory after ui-router state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a list of icons on a webpage generated from an object array. When the user clicks on an icon, the corresponding object from the array is passed to a function in a factory which saves the name of the object selected, then `$state.go` is called to change routes. On the new route a controller is loaded which loads the same factory and tries to access the name of the saved object. The problem is that about 7 times out of 10, it works perfectly, and the other 3 times is gives a "Unable to get property 'name' of undefined or null reference" type error.

Here is the controller passing the selected value to the factory:

```
platformHome.controller('PlatformHome', ['$scope', 'appManager', '$state',  function ($scope, appManager, $state) {

    var SF = appManager.state.SF;
    var SO = appManager.state.SO;

    $scope.productLineSelected = function (product) {
       setProductLine(product);                     
    };

    function setProductLine(product) {
        SF.setProduct(product);
        $state.go('metricDashboard');       
    }

}]);
```

Here is the factory:

```
applicationManager.factory('appStateManager', ['$rootScope', '$sessionStorage', '$state', function ($rootScope, $sessionStorage, $state) {

//    STATE OBJECT CLASSES
//
var stateClasses = {};

stateClasses.ProductLine = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dashboard = {
        mode: 'reporting', //reporting, analysis
        modeView: 'canvas', //canvas, data
        index: {
            report: 0,
            userReport: 0,
            canvas: 0,
            group: 0,
            element: 0,
            filter: 0,
        }
    };
    this.reports = [];
    this.canvases = [new stateClasses.Canvas];
};


//    STATE DATA FUNCTIONS
//
var stateFunctions = {};

stateFunctions.setProduct = function (product) {
    session.StateObject.productLine.current = product.Code;
    session.StateObject[product.Code] = (typeof session.StateObject[product.Code] === 'undefined') ? new stateClasses.ProductLine(product.Name) : session.StateObject[product.Code];
};


//    STUCTURE
//
var stateScope = $rootScope.$new(true);

var session = $sessionStorage;
session.StateObject = (typeof session.StateObject === 'undefined') ? new stateClasses.StateObject : session.StateObject;

stateScope.SO = session.StateObject;
stateScope.SF = stateFunctions;

return stateScope;

}]);
```

Here is the controller trying to access the name:

```
metricDashboard.controller('MetricDashboard', ['$scope', 'appManager', function ($scope, appManager) {

    var SF = appManager.state.SF;
    var SO = appManager.state.SO;

    DSO = SO[SO.productLine.current];
    $scope.name = DSO.name;

}]);
```

I suspect that the issue is related to the order in which things are happening, however, I cannot figure out why it works 7 times out of 10.

When I do get the error, I have been able to determine that the line `SO.productLine.current` in the second controller has a value of `none`, meaning it doesn't seem to have been updated from the scope of the controller, however, at the same time, I'm also using `console.log(JSON.stringify())` inside the factory, and the factory does indeed show a proper value instead of `none`.

I've also tried using `$timeout` on `$state.go`, and also tried passing it as a callback, however neither of those prevent the issue. Again 7 times out of 10, the code runs fine and the name property is value, but sometimes its not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to correct the problem with a few steps. The idea is to remove the assignment of the `DSO` variable from the `MetricDashboard` controller and move that functionality of assignment into the factory, then simply reference the newly assigned variable back in the controller.

Here are the changes:

**In Factory**

```
...

//    STATE DATA FUNCTIONS
//
var stateFunctions = {};

stateFunctions.setProduct = function (product) {
    session.StateObject.productLine.current = product.Code;
    session.StateObject[product.Code] = (typeof session.StateObject[product.Code] === 'undefined') ? new stateClasses.ProductLine(product.Name) : session.StateObject[product.Code];

        //new functionality for assignment
        session.DynamicStateObject = session.StateObject[product.Code];
        stateScope.DSO = session.DynamicStateObject;
};


//    STUCTURE
//
var stateScope = $rootScope.$new(true);

var session = $sessionStorage;
session.StateObject = (typeof session.StateObject === 'undefined') ? new stateClasses.StateObject : session.StateObject;

    //new structure to persist assignment beyond page refresh
    session.DynamicStateObject = (typeof session.DynamicStateObject === 'undefined') ? {} : session.DynamicStateObject;

    //new reference
    stateScope.DSO = session.DynamicStateObject;

stateScope.SO = session.StateObject;
stateScope.SF = stateFunctions;

return stateScope;
```

**In Controller**

```
var SF = appManager.state.SF;
var SO = appManager.state.SO;

//Removed assignmnet
//DSO = SO[SO.productLine.current];

//Added reference
var DSO = appManager.state.DSO;

$scope.name = DSO.name;
```

While I have not yet tested the new code extensively, I have not been able reproduce the error.